# Getting an element to overlap an image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get this h1 tag with an image inside to overlap the div below it (including it's child elements, which are floated inside).

Using a negative margin works in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox or IE. Interestingly the parent div is respecting my wishes, and allowing itself to be overlapped, but the floated image inside that div is not. It is getting pushed over to the side because of the negative margin, even though I have given it a z-index of -1.

HTML:

```
<header>
<h1 class="logo">
    <img src="images/blush-header-logo.png">
    <span>Blush Wedding + Lifestyle</span></h1>

    <nav>
    <h1 class="hidden">Navigation</h1>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">The Magazine</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Featured Weddings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vendors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="banner">
        <img src="images/blush-banner.jpg">
            <aside class="current-issue">
        <h2>Latest issue</h2>
        <h3>Spring &bull; Summer 2013</h3>
        <p>Featuring an exclusive interview....</p>
        <button href="#">Purchase Here</button>
            </aside>
            <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

CSS:

```
header{
    position: relative;
}

header h1, header li{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

header h1.logo{
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 220px;
    height: 183px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

header h1.logo span{
    display: none;
}

header .banner{
    margin-top: -21px;
    z-index: -5;
    position: static;
}

header .banner img{
    float: left;
    z-index: -1;
}

header .banner aside{
    padding: 70px 18px 0 18px;
    float: left;
    width: 28%;
}
```

http://pixeldesigns.ca/files/blush/index.html

Is there a way to get this to work without absolutely positioning the image?

Comment: Please post your actual code rather than a link.  Your link will be dead in short time, and without code here, your question won't be able to help others in the future.

Comment: what about using the image as background?

Comment: @arieljuod interesting idea, I think that would work really well - it's going to be a WordPress site though so that could prove tricky.

Comment: it is not tricky, just set the image as a background for your .banner with no-repeat and a fixed height so the image is not cutted, then you can position the background with background-position, i could add a jsfiddle but i have no time right now

Comment: @arieljuod - it would have to be inline css right?

Comment: done, you can do that on your css file, it's better that way, you can do that inline inside your html but it's not recomended

Comment: @arieljuod - what I was wondering is how would I get the image url from the wordpress db within the css file ? that's why I thought it would have to be inline css.

Comment: oh, didn't know the image came from WP database, do you really need it to come from the database? in that case yes, you do have to make that inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any code, but you already done it so you can put the code that worked for you. Should be something like:

```
.banner {
  background: url(yourimage'surl) no-repeat 0% 0%;
  height: yourimage'sheight;
}
```

if you need more images or even background color/gradients you can separete them by comma

something like:

```
background: url(yourimage'surl) no-repeat 0% 0%, url(anotherimage) no-repeat 100% 100%, #888;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position: relative;` and `display: block;` for negative margins to work

Answer (score 0):

Positioning the image absolute inside your `h1` is your best option. If you then want to reposition the image you can give in some margin or padding.
Negative margins and browser compatibility is really not best friends

```
.logo img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

If you apply

```
header .banner {
    float: left;
}
```

This will fix it for IE and Firefox but will break it for Chrome.
You can then maybe user a hack to apply this style only to IE and Firefox...but i wouldn't recommend this

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    header .banner {float: left;}
}

<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<style>
    header .banner {float: left;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```