# Which way is better? Resorting to a background image or using absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, seo

I am developing a Wordpress website where I needed the logo to overlap the banner image below.

Through the help of a colleague as well as Stack Overflow users I now have two solutions that allow for my layout to render as intended.

1. The image in the banner is rendered as a background image. Because this is a Wordpress site I will have to use inline css for this. [Link.](http://pixeldesigns.ca/files/blush/)
2. The nav and the banner below are positioned absolutely. [Link.](http://pixeldesigns.ca/files/blush/index2.html)

Problems with solution #1:

I realized that if the image is rendered as a background image it will be less SEO friendly and of course less user-friendly for screen readers, etc. as it won't have alt or title tags.

Problems with solution #2:

I find that absolute positioning just doesn't feel as reliable cross-browser (this could be all in my mind). This method also required some extra markup and css classes which I didn't like having to do.

**Which way do you think is better? For what reasons?**

Comment: this type of question depends on your needs and is primarily opinion based..

Comment: You could do this with an image and without position absolute anyway. These aren't the only two solutions. Just position relative on both and put a negative margin on the banner div. Use z-index for the correct overlap.

Comment: @Zach Z-index didn't seem to work with the banner image, only with text. I'd be really interested to see a demo of your solution. See my question regarding that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602677/getting-an-element-to-overlap-an-image

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/zach123/rPJzM/ It might take some tweaking of styles that you already are using but this is the idea, no absolute position and you can use text in the banner div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a definitive answer to your question.

But bear in mind that if you want to print your page, the background image will not be rendered, but the absolute image will.

in my opinion: you should ask yourself if this image is part of the content in your web site, or just a nice visual style.
if its part of the content: use absolute positioning techniques, otherwise: use background.

Comment: Good points to keep in mind re: printing and visual style vs content.